# What happens when an array of base objects gets an instance of child objects as one of its cells?

Tags: c#, arrays, parent-child

I have an array of `Tiles[w,h]` and by mistake I could (without any obvious errors, so I guess this is okay to do) assign a child object `LibraryTile` to one of its cells. It shows up as LibraryTile in intellisense hover popup.

I'm not sure if it will not bring any undesired effects, like increased memory consumption (it's a memberwise copy, not a reference), so I don't know if I should change my methods or if it is fine to leave them as is.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? `LibraryTile` is derived from a `Tile`, and you assigned an instance of `LibraryTile` to a slot in an array of `Tile`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `Tiles[2,3] = new LibraryTile();`

Comment: Need more detail, code would help a lot

Comment: You consider it undesirable compared to what?  What else would you do?

Comment: The fact that you can assign child class instance is normal in OOP languages, it all about inheritance in OOP. Do you clone your instances because I presume that LibraryTile is class not a struct.

Comment: That's the whole point of OOP. A `dog` **is** an `animal`. So if you have a list of `animal`s, it's perfectly normal than one of them is a `dog`. But btw, is there a reason for cloning the object (i.e. creating a memberwise copy)?

Comment: There's no question here or any code, how should people answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume LibraryTile is a subclass of Tile?  Which is why you tagged it as parent-child?

What you're seeing is just polymorphism.  It will "act" like a Tile, just the same.  Whether or not it consumes more memory depends on what LibraryTile adds to its base class.  You can test at runtime if Tile is an actual LibraryTile and, if so, cast to a LIbraryTile to do "special stuff" so to say.  But without more context, I can't advise you on techniques to take advantage of polymorphism (e.g. virtual methods, interfaces, etc).

If you don't want to allow inheritance for whatever reason, you can seal your parent class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx